# Translating Menu Item Programmatically?

Tags: i18n-l10n, navigation

I have been trying to translate menu items programmatically but upon saving it just adds the english field value to all my translations.
Below is the code I am trying to execute:

```
 if ($entity->hasTranslation($language->getId())) {
      //For update
      $entity->removeTranslation($language->getId());
    }
    try {
      $entity->addTranslation($language->getId(), ['title' => 'abcd'])->save();
    } catch (EntityStorageException $e) {
      \Drupal::logger('Menu-Translation')->error($e->getMessage());
      \Drupal::messenger()->addError(t('Failed to add translation for ' . $language->getName()));
    }
```

I am debugging and I think the issue lies in the line :

```
$entity->addTranslation($language->getId(), ['title' => 'abcd'])->save();
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thankyou.

Comment: Just a sanity check - is the "Menu link title" field configured to be translatable at /admin/config/regional/content-language?

Comment: How are you implementing localization? Menu items should have a 'translate' link (or something similar) in the menu UI (structure -> menus).

Answer (score 1):

You didn't take into account the default language.  Your code will break if you're running this code on a callback in the default language, because you remove the default translation, and you're not allowed to do that:

```
$defaultLanguage = \Drupal::languageManager->getDefaultLanguage()->getId();
if ($entity->hasTranslation($language->getId()) && $language->getId() !== $defaultLanguage) {
  // For update
  $entity->removeTranslation($language->getId());
}
try {
  if ($language->getId() === $defaultLanguage) {
    // Just set the field value, not the translation:
    $entity->set('title', 'abcd');
  }
  else {
    $entity->addTranslation($language->getId(), ['title' => 'abcd'])->save();
  }
} catch (EntityStorageException $e) {
  \Drupal::logger('Menu-Translation')->error($e->getMessage());
  \Drupal::messenger()->addError(t('Failed to add translation for ' . $language->getName()));
}
```